# Geometry needed to layout points in a grid for a centered hexagonal number?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, polygons

I asked this as a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77922222/how-to-layout-draw-a-centered-hexagonal-number-in-html-javascript), but perhaps it is a better math question. What is the math needed to compute the positions of the points along the flat edges of the hexagon? I could then translate that math into code to layout the points :). Are there simple equations to do it? Or does it just require brute force thinking about each point?

Answer (score 2):

I had coded Regular polygons $ r=f(\theta)$for plotting using PolarPlot  as follows:

> ```
> n = 6; a = 1; PolarPlot[ 
>  a Sec[ArcCos[Cos[ n theta ]]/n],  {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]
> ```

[image]

This regular polygon of $n$ sides escribes a unit circle.

Comment: Mind adding an explanation of what those functions are or do? Then I will mark as correct but it is a little opaque for me without knowing what seems like MatLab.

Comment: It is standard trig in Mathematica. ArcCos [..] is $\cos^ {-1}(..) $ etc.